# How to derive 95% CI of hazard ratio from another estimate with different bounds?

Tags: confidence-interval

I am working on a meta-analysis and pooling hazard ratio (HR). One of the included studies (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31536101) has reported 95.47% confidence interval (CI) of the HR (HR, 0.98 [95.47% CI, 0.84-1.14]); however, I need 95% CI to pool this estimate. I do not have individual patient data, but only the summary estimates reported in the published study. Could you please suggest how can I derive 95% CI form the reported data?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on r/askreddit (responded by u/COOLSerdash). Instead of deriving 95% CIs, I tried calculating SEs, since that's what is needed to pool HRs. Since, on a log scale, HR approximate normal distribution, so log(CI) = log(HR) +/- Z (alpha/2) * SE.